# Confused on GET and POST Method

Tags: php, html

What I have learnt is: At a time, only HTTP POST or GET method is possible. I have the following piece of code named: index.php

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    echo "Request Method is: ". $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] .'<br>';
    echo "Get variable is: " . $_GET['getname'] . '<br>';
    echo "Post variable is: " . $_POST['posttitle'];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing Get or Post</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="posttitle" value="somepost"/>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I navigate the form via : http://localhost/testing/index.php?getname=someget. I submit the form, and the form data is sent via HTTP POST method.

Now my question is: 
In this scenario, the HTTP method is POST, and the GET variable $_GET['getname'] should have been unavailable. But, both POST and GET variables are available and printed.

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit better? maybe you can also use a questionmark after your question

Comment: `$_GET` will return your data from url query string. So if you pass any data from query string you can retrieve it in `$_GET`  at any time. That is not the issue

Comment: If you define a query/get variable in your URL, it's available. That's really all there is to it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48585806/476

Comment: You can actually check for a POST request with if($_POST)

Comment: @maio290 — No, you can't. That tests if there is any POST data. It is possible to have a POST request with nothing in the request body.

Comment: In his example he can do it and it's legit to do so - and yeah, you can send an empty post request, and yeah, you can construct any weird case for being right. But in his example this will simply work.

Comment: @maio290 There's a difference between an absolute true statement and something that works in a specific case.

Comment: There is simply no use in sending an empty post request. Why should you send a post request when you don't sent any data with it? This doesn't follow any good practice of software design. The main problem is that I didn't add a "here". But discussing on SO is a pain in the arse anyway.

Comment: If both GET and POST are available, $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] should have returned both GET and POST, right ?

Comment: @maio290 In a RESTful API there are perfectly valid use cases for sending empty POST requests. The verb "POST" in itself has a meaning, typically of *creating a new resource*, and it's perfectly fine to tell a server to create a new resource without any additional arguments.

Comment: @ShilanTitaju — No. See the answer I gave you quarter of an hour ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just down to PHP having poor names for `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

`$_GET` will contain data from the query string of the requested URL. This is completely independent of the request method used.

PHP probably picked the name because an HTML form with `method="GET"` will put the data in the query string, but that isn't the only way a query string can be created.

Comment: You usually don't receive GET and POST parameters at the same time. Therefore I wouldn't say that PHP has bad names for $_GET and $_POST.

Comment: "You usually don't receive GET and POST parameters at the same time." – It is not all that uncommon for a request to include a query string and a body.

Comment: @maio290 It's perfectly cromulent to `POST` to a URL containing query parameters. How "unusual" is that…?

Comment: Following for example REST standards, you never have any query parameters. And in basic PHP with HTML you don't have it either..

Comment: @maio290 — "And in basic PHP with HTML you don't have it either." — Rubbish. PHP makes it very easy to have that. I've worked with code that does that plenty of times.

Comment: Mhm, I've never seen a <form method="POST&GET"> ;)

Comment: @maio290 — I refer you to my original answer. A request with a query string is not the same thing is a request using the GET method.  `<form action="foo.php?x=y" method="POST">` (More commonly it would be done by not having an action attribute and just preserving the query string from the page being viewed)

Comment: But according to several posts here at SO, `method="post" action="save.php?parm=yes"` do not receive the parm

Comment: @mplungjan — Those will all be questions about forms which are `method="GET"`. We're talking about POST requests.

Comment: @Quentin I mean these, there are MANY https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35665520/how-can-i-send-post-with-query-string-in-a-link?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @mplungjan — That's about a link that makes a GET request not populating `$_POST`, not a form that makes a POST request that is populating `$_GET`. It's about as opposite to the situation as I described as you can get.